# How to break the title of tab in IconTabBar in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to Break the title of Tab in IconTab Component.

I tried by using the CSS. By default it has width as auto. I changes this to some 5rem after that my title is displaying with elipses [eg., I am title...., the actual title is I am title Here].

My Code look like this:

```
                <items>

                    <!--  Tab -->

                    <IconTabFilter text="I am Title Here">
                        <content>
                        </content>
                    </IconTabFilter>
              </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

I am getting like this in my system.

[image: I am getting like this.]

The Actual Design look like this:

[image]

My Css is like this:

[image]

In this it is first applying the width auto. Then i override that style to 5rem. you can see in my screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean... The default width of the title  is actually set to `5rem` and not `auto`.

If you set `width:auto;` you won't get a line break, but your tab title at least is visible.

A line break may be possible, but you need to change a lot more CSS (IconTabBar height etc)

EDIT: I was under the impression you would show an icon too. If that is not the case, simply set property `showAll="true"` and no need to alter CSS :)

See this working example:

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
    onInit: function(oEvent) {}
});

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
    viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
});

oView.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

    <title>SAPUI5 example</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

    <script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
        <mvc:View
          height="100%"
          controllerName="view1.initial"
          xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
          xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
          xmlns="sap.m">
            <IconTabBar
              id="idIconTabBar"
              select="handleIconTabBarSelect">
                <items>
                <IconTabFilter
                  showAll="true"
                  text="Some pretty long text"
                  keys="All" />
                <IconTabSeparator />
                <IconTabFilter
                  showAll="true"
                  iconColor="Positive"
                  text="Hi I'm a title"
                  key="Ok" />
                <IconTabFilter
                  iconColor="Critical"
                  text="Heavy"
                  key="Heavy" />
                <IconTabFilter
                  iconColor="Negative"
                  text="Overweight"
                  key="Overweight" />
                </items>
            </IconTabBar>
        </mvc:View>
    </script>

</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="uiArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the layout settings of the SAPUI5 theme in your own CSS file, by adding !important tags to your CSS. This is a 'quick and dirty' solution, which works well but can become difficult to manage in large quantities.

Say you want to change the width to 50%, you would add the following to your CSS file:

```
.sapMITBTextOnly .sapMITBText{
width: 50% !important;
}
```